# MS Access: Viewing SQL for tables, relationships etc and not just queries

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get some help online for my Access created database in an SQL chatroom but I am being asked to show the SQL for it. I am unable to do this and it seems the SQL View function only shows up for queries and not tables or relationships etc.

Nothing comes up online and I have been told that it is apparently possible to code in raw SQL in Access for everything (and I imagine view the database code) so could someone please tell me how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much easier to just create a screenshot of the relationship window and send it to them. If you are using window 7 you could just use the snipping tool on the fly.:)

Other thing you could do is create a query and add the affected tables in the query builder then switch to SQL view. you should be able to see the joins from there.

Comment: That was the 1st thing I did lol They just kept telling me to give them the SQL...I think they didn't even bother to click on the link and see for themselves. I had a DBM yesterday help me out on IRC and he managed to do that from the Relationships screenshot...I have started to realise how odd and inflexible most nerds actually are!

Comment: Ok I've made a small edit to my answer hope it's useful.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for...however, now they are still not satisfied as I don't speak tech like they do so I can't actually describe in geek talk what my problem in so I imagine they think it is not worth their while :( 

I have wasted 8hrs trying to sort this out when I have an assignment to finish for tomorrow only to find out that geeks seem inflexible, don't appear very dynamic and can't (don't) seem to (want) to deal with problems when you are novice. Why did I choose this career path! lol

Comment: If you want you can post your problem here and what you have tried so far solve it and you'll get solutions. Sometimes there are more than one way to solve a particular problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was considering to do that but I didn't want to be banned for being too subjective etc as I posted before about a question on a Java program I wrote and it was considered too broad lol

Rather than repeat myself, if you look at the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases

you can see what my issue is. I have still been trying to sort it but it seems to get more and more complicated lol

I have 18hrs until I need to submit and the database part with all queries, reports and forms is 45 marks so I am giving up and deciding to focus on the paperwork!